# Fastest way to resolve ListItem from ItemId in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

What is the fastest way to check the content type of a list item in SharePoint 2010 when all I have is the SiteId (site collection) and ItemId (the GUID)? (I also have the SPSite instance)

I am reading audit log entries and need additional properties of the list item in order to filter the entries. The entries will all be from the same site collection, but from different lists and webs.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have UniqueID or just ID ?

With ID , you cannot determine the list, since its just an integer.

If you have the UniqueID, fastest way would be to fire SPSiteDataQuery to retrieve the SPListItem and then get the SPList.

http://vspug.com/mykiep/2007/05/09/getting-an-splistitem-by-it-s-unique-id/

Avoid iterating SPWeb and SPList to find the matching  UniqueID. It will be too slow.